# Powershell: How to create custom object and pass it to function in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to create a custom object with properties in PowerShell and then pass that object to a function. I found the online example to create custom object, but its using HashTable. However, I have single object with properties, not an array of objects.

1. If possible, I would like to create single object instead of
   HashTable.
2. If HashTables are the way to go, how do I retrieve the
   object and pass it to a function?

Below is a sample of my code:

```
function CreateObject()
{       
  $properties = @{      
    'TargetServer' = “ServerName”;
    'ScriptPath' = “SomePath”;
    'ServiceName' = "ServiceName"
 }

   $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties    

   Write-Output $obj.TargetServer
   Write-Output $obj.ScriptPath
   Write-Output $obj.ServiceName

   return $obj
}

 function Function2([PSObject] $obj)
{   
   Do something here with $obj
}


$myObj = CreateObject

Function2 $myObj
```

**EDIT 1**
Thanks @Frode and @Matt. I didn't know that 'return' statement would return other results also. Will the following work?

```
function CreateObject()
{      
    return New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{     
       'TargetServer' = "ServerName"
       'ScriptPath' = "SomePath"
       'ServiceName' = "ServiceName"
      }
}

function Init()
{
   // Do something here

   $myObject = CreateObject()

  // Do something here with $myObject

  return $myObject
}

function Funcntion2([PSObject] $obj)
{
  //Do somthing with $obj
}

$obj = Init

Function2 $obj
```

Comment: You could also use just do this

return [PSCustomObject]$obj = @{
    'TargetServer' = “ServerName”;
    'ScriptPath' = “SomePath”;
    'ServiceName' = "ServiceName"
}

Comment: [Powershell: Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [about_return](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) Its important to know that

> In Windows PowerShell, the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword.

So as [Frode said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35904977/3829407) you are going to be getting a string array. You want to be returning your object as a whole and not its parts. If the purpose of your function is just to return that custom object then you can reduce that statement to a single line.

```
function CreateObject()
{      
    return New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{     
        'TargetServer' = "ServerName"
        'ScriptPath' = "SomePath"
        'ServiceName' = "ServiceName"
    }
}
```

If you have at least PowerShell 3.0 then you can use the `[pscustomobject]` type cast to accomplish the same thing.

```
function CreateObject()
{      
    return [pscustomobject] @{     
        'TargetServer' = "ServerName"
        'ScriptPath' = "SomePath"
        'ServiceName' = "ServiceName"
    }
}
```

Note that in both cases the `return` keyword is optional but know that it does still serve a purpose as a logical exit of a function (all output until that point is still returned).

If you don't need to save the results of the function in a variable you can also just chain that into your next function.

```
Function2 (CreateObject)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are creating an object. The hash table is just placeholder used to define all properties before turning them into an object.

Remove the three lines starting with `write-output` and you should be good. They are unnecessary and makes your function return an array and not just the object like you wanted. Use `write-host` if you only want to display the values to the screen while testing.