# create object in powershell

Tags: powershell, object

I need to create an object and each iteration add values to. The problem what i have is I thing with the logic of the code. I think I have to create another `foreach` and place `New-Object psobject -Property $object` outside...but i don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me?

```
Import-Module BEMCLI  #BackupExec

$object= @{}
#For each last 15 job backups
ForEach ($i in $(Get-BEJob "FULL" | Get-BEJobHistory -FromStartTime (Get-Date).AddDays("-15") -JobType Backup))
 { 

 $object.TAPE= ($i | Get-BEJobLog | Get-BEJobLogFiles) # get Tape
 $object.START_TIME=$i.StartTime #get starttime
 $object.END_TIME=$i.EndTime #get endtime

 New-Object psobject -Property $object
 } 

$object | ft
```

Comment: "I need to create an object and each iteration add values to".. What? All BEJobs in the same single object? What output are you looking for? The usual solution is to create an object per BEJob and collect them in an array (list of objects).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I still struggle with objects and arrays. Thanks.

Comment: [Powershell: Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: How to create custom object and pass it to function in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904863/powershell-how-to-create-custom-object-and-pass-it-to-function-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `foreach` construct you have looks like it is designed to send data down the pipeline. Not only are you not attempting to capture the data it does not send items down the pipeline anyway. The *simplest* thing to change would be to assign the `foreach` loop to a variable

```
Import-Module BEMCLI  #BackupExec

#For each last 15 job backups
$objects = ForEach ($i in $(Get-BEJob "FULL" | Get-BEJobHistory -FromStartTime (Get-Date).AddDays("-15") -JobType Backup))
{ 
    $object = @{} # Wipe object for next run. 
    $object.TAPE= ($i | Get-BEJobLog | Get-BEJobLogFiles) # get Tape
    $object.START_TIME=$i.StartTime #get starttime
    $object.END_TIME=$i.EndTime #get endtime

    New-Object psobject -Property $object
} 

$objects | ft
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another Array Object, and add your `$object` data into it on every iteration

```
Import-Module BEMCLI  #BackupExec

$Array = @()
$object= @{}
#For each last 15 job backups
ForEach ($i in $(Get-BEJob "FULL" | Get-BEJobHistory -FromStartTime (Get-Date).AddDays("-15") -JobType Backup))
 { 

 $object.TAPE= ($i | Get-BEJobLog | Get-BEJobLogFiles) # get Tape
 $object.START_TIME=$i.StartTime #get starttime
 $object.END_TIME=$i.EndTime #get endtime

 $Array += $Object
 } 

$Array | ft
```