# PowerShell - How to tell if two objects are identical

Tags: powershell, object, if-statement, conditional-statements, equality

Let's say you have two objects that are identical (meaning they have the same properties and the same values respectively).

How do you test for equality?

**Example**

`$obj1` & `$obj2` are identical

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
if($obj1 -eq $obj2)
{
    echo 'true'
} else {
    echo 'false'
}
# RETURNS "false"

if(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $obj1 -DifferenceObject $obj2)
{
    echo 'true'
} else {
    echo 'false'
}
# RETURNS "false"
```

**Edit**

This is **not** identical

[image]

Comment: Use `Compare-Object -IncludeEqual` otherwise it only tells you the differences.  Otherwise, if there is no return, it was successful.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 not quite what I was looking for. If I add a property to `$obj1`, `-IncludeEqual` will still return `$true`

Comment: check my answer.  It should work how you expect.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I just ran a test. If you add a new property to one object, it still returns "true", even though in true essence the two objects are not equal

Comment: FTR, there's a difference between identity and equality in object orientation. Identity means you have the exact same object (same object reference), whereas two distinct objects with the same property values are just equal, not identical.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Am I looking for "Identical" or "Equal" based on my above question? a little confused. I basically want the object to be exactly the same in every way. No difference at all

Comment: I remember using `Compare-Object $obj1.PsObject.Properties $obj2.PsObject.Properties`, but I don't remember if that's complete anymore or if it just works for PSCustomObjects.

Comment: @BaconBits Yeah, at this point I'm wondering if I'm going to have to loop through all properties an values of each object

Comment: Well, no, I mean that's what `Compare-Object $obj1.PsObject.Properties $obj2.PsObject.Properties` already does.  The only additional think I can thing to do would be to add `$obj1.GetType() -eq $obj2.GetType()`.

Comment: Don't post picture output. Use code formatting and paste the output as text.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Why do I get a downvote on every question I ever ask from you? What exactly is unclear about my question?

Comment: @KolobCanyon I didn't downvote your question. Perhaps someone else downvoted because you used pictures instead of pasting output text? (Wasn't me, though; I thought it was a good question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare two `PSObject` objects for equality of properties and values by using `Compare-Object` to compare the `Properties` properties of both `PSObject`objects. Example:

```
if ( -not (Compare-Object $obj1.PSObject.Properties $obj2.PSObject.Properties) ) {
  "object properties and values match"
}
else {
  "object properties and values do not match"
}
```

If you want it in a function:

```
function Test-PSCustomObjectEquality {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [PSCustomObject] $firstObject,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [PSCustomObject] $secondObject
  )
  -not (Compare-Object $firstObject.PSObject.Properties $secondObject.PSObject.Properties)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `Compare-Object` for this task:

```
Function Test-Objects
{
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
    [PSCustomObject]$Obj1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=1)]
    [PSCustomObject]$Obj2
    )

    [Void](Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Obj1.PSObject.Properties -DifferenceObject.PSObject.Properties $Obj2 -OutVariable 'Test')

    ## Tests whether they are equal, no return = success
    If (-not $Test)
    {
        $True
    }
    Else
    {
        $False
    }
}
```

---

```
PS C:\> $Obj1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Property1 = 'Value1'
    Property2 = 'Value2'
    Property3 = 'Value3'
    Property4 = 'Value4'
    Property5 = 'Value5'
}
PS C:\> $Obj2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Property1 = 'Value1'
    Property2 = 'Value2'
    Property3 = 'Value3'
    Property4 = 'Value4'
    Property5 = 'Value5'
}
PS C:\> Test-Objects $Obj1 $Obj2
True
PS C:\> $Obj2 | Add-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name 'Prop6' -Value 'Value6'
PS C:\> Test-Objects $Obj1 $Obj2
False
```

Comment: Say you do this... `$obj1 | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'NewProperty' -NotePropertyValue 'NewValue'`... if you run the code above it still considers `$obj1` equal to `$obj2`, even though they are not. I just tested it

Comment: Compare-Object uses `ToString()` for comparison - this is unreliable. Use `$obj1 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = 7; }; $obj2 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'c' = '6'; 'b' = 7; }` for example - it says they are equal. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346380/1244910

Comment: @KolobCanyon That is factually wrong.  In my testing (v2, v5), it worked properly.

Comment: Why `if (-not $Test) { $true } else { $false }` when you can write simply `-not $Test`?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I was too focused on his question example, but you're absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to test for equality for every object property, one at a time, in order to compare and contrast two objects and see which individual pieces are different, you can use the following function, adapted from this article on how to [compare all properties of two objects in Windows PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/janesays/2017/04/25/compare-all-properties-of-two-objects-in-windows-powershell/)

```bash
Function Compare-ObjectProperties {
    Param(
        [PSObject]$leftObj,
        [PSObject]$rightObj 
    )

    $leftProps = $leftObj.PSObject.Properties.Name
    $rightProps = $rightObj.PSObject.Properties.Name
    $allProps = $leftProps + $rightProps | Sort | Select -Unique

    $props = @()

    foreach ($propName in $allProps) {

        # test if has prop
        $leftHasProp = $propName -in $leftProps
        $rightHasProp = $propName -in $rightProps

        # get value from object
        $leftVal = $leftObj.$propName
        $rightVal = $rightObj.$propName

        # create custom output - 
        $prop = [pscustomobject] @{   
            Match = $(If ($propName -eq "SamAccountName" ) {"1st"} Else {
                        $(If ($leftHasProp -and !$rightHasProp ) {"Left"} Else {
                            $(If ($rightHasProp -and !$leftHasProp ) {"Right"} Else {
                                $(If ($leftVal -eq $rightVal ) {"Same"} Else {"Diff"})
                            })
                          })
                     })
            PropName = $propName
            LeftVal = $leftVal
            RightVal = $rightVal
        }

        $props += $prop
    }

    # sort & format table widths
    $props | Sort-Object Match, PropName | Format-Table -Property `
               @{ Expression={$_.Match}; Label="Match"; Width=6}, 
               @{ Expression={$_.PropName}; Label="Property Name"; Width=25}, 
               @{ Expression={$_.LeftVal }; Label="Left Value";    Width=40}, 
               @{ Expression={$_.RightVal}; Label="Right Value";   Width=40}

}
```

And then use like this:

```bash
$adUser1 = Get-ADUser 'Grace.Hopper' -Properties *
$adUser2 = Get-ADUser 'Katherine.Johnson' -Properties *   
Compare-ObjectProperties $adUser1 $adUser2
```

**Couple Interesting Notes**:

- [How to Test if Element Has Property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982801/1366033)
- [How to Get Property Value by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406385/1366033)
- [How to Create a Custom PS Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905423/1366033)
- [How to Create a Nested Conditional / Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311158/1366033)
- [How to Format Table with fixed Widths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52174495/1366033)
- Attempted to Colorize output with [VT Escape Sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038815/1366033) or [`Write-PSObject`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Format-Table-Colors-in-e0a4beac), but couldn't get it to work with fixed column widths which took priority

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I used:

```
function Test-ObjectEquality {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $Object1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $Object2
    )

    return !(Compare-Object $Object1.PSObject.Properties $Object2.PSObject.Properties)
}
```

Examples:

```
PS C:\> $obj1 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = 7; };
PS C:\> $obj2 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = 7; };
PS C:\> Test-ObjectEquality $obj1 $obj2
True
PS C:\> $obj2 = [psobject] @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = 7; };
PS C:\> Test-ObjectEquality $obj1 $obj2
False
PS C:\> $obj2 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = 7; };
PS C:\> Test-ObjectEquality $obj1 $obj2
True
PS C:\> $obj2 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'c' = '6'; 'b' = 7; };
PS C:\> Test-ObjectEquality $obj1 $obj2
False
PS C:\> $obj2 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = 8; };
PS C:\> Test-ObjectEquality $obj1 $obj2
False
PS C:\> $obj2 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = 7; c = 8 };
PS C:\> Test-ObjectEquality $obj1 $obj2
False
PS C:\> $obj2 = [pscustomobject] @{ 'a' = '5'; 'b' = '7'; };
PS C:\> Test-ObjectEquality $obj1 $obj2
False
```

I certainly believe it's possible for this to miss things; however, if you look at what's in `Properties` you can see what's being compared for every property on an object:

```
PS C:\> $obj1.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -First 1


MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : 5
TypeNameOfValue : System.String
Name            : a
IsInstance      : True
```

It's not often that I've cared about more than the `MemberType`, `Name`, `TypeNameOfValue`, or `Value` of an object's properties.

Also, note that if you really need to, you can compare `.PSObject.Members` instead of `.PSObject.Properties`.  That will compare properties and methods, although you're only comparing the method calls and not the method definitions.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a function that checks for *exact* equality:

```
 function Global:Test-IdenticalObjects
 {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Object1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Object2,
        $SecondRun=$false
    )

    if(-not ($Object1 -is [PsCustomObject] -and $Object2 -is [PsCustomObject))
    {
        Write-Error "Objects must be PsCustomObjects"
        return
    }

    foreach($property1 in $Object1.PsObject.Properties)
    {
        $prop1_name = $property1.Name
        $prop1_value = $Object1.$prop1_name
        $found_property = $false
        foreach($property2 in $Object2.PsObject.Properties)
        {
            $prop2_name = $property2.Name
            $prop2_value = $Object2.$prop2_name
            if($prop1_name -eq $prop2_name)
            {
                $found_property = $true
                if($prop1_value -ne $prop2_value)
                {
                    return $false
                }
            }
        } # j loop
        if(-not $found_property) { return $false }
    } # i loop
    if($SecondRun)
    {
        return $true
    } else {
        Test-IdenticalObjects -Object1 $Object2 -Object2 $Object1 -SecondRun $true
    }
 } # function
```

Comment: 1) Don't recommend `global:` scope ID. 2) Lots of unnecessary work and overhead; a single `Compare-Object` will do (see my answer).