# Comparing two VMHostVirtualSwitches that always show equal

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powercli

I am comparing a predetermined object (VMHostVirtualSwitch Name) value with all object(VMHostVirtualSwitch Names) values within a collection of objects and want the status to be "FAIL" if the objects don't match

I have written the following code so far but it doesn't seem to be working. I know the objects don't match and I should get "FAIL" as an output

```
$VMHostVirtualSwitch = Get-VMHostNetwork -VMHost abc.com | Select-Object VirtualSwitch*
$Cluster = Get-Cluster -VMHost abc.com 
$VMHosts = Get-Cluster $Cluster | Get-VMHost
[int]$Switchcount=0

foreach ($VMHost in $VMHosts){
  $CurrentHostVirtualSwitch = Get-VMHostNetwork -VMHost $VMHost | Select-Object VirtualSwitch*
  if ($CurrentHostVirtualSwitch -ne $VMHostVirtualSwitch) {
   $Switchcount++
  }
}
if($Switchcount -ge 1) {
Write-Output "FAIL"
}
```

`$VMHostVirtualSwitch` has the following value

```
VirtualSwitch
-------------
{vSwitch3}
```

When I expand the `$VMHostVirtualSwitch` , I get the following values

```
Name                           NumPorts   Mtu   Notes                                             
----                           --------   ---   -----                                             
vSwitch3                       10562      2340
```

Comment: I can't tell but what is the type of `VirtualSwitch`? I ask because PowerShell might just be comparing types and not the object data. You might be better off expanding the property in both cases-> `| Select-Object -Expand VirtualSwitch` so you are working directly against the values. If the type does not support comparison operators you might still have to do this manually.

Comment: I have edited my question and able to `Expand the value`. How can I just compare just the `VirtualSwitch Name`?

Comment: Ah ok. So that is the problem then. PowerShell does not know how to compare the objects. You could just expand the name as well. `Select-Object -expand VirtualSwitch | select-object -expand name` or `(Get-VMHostNetwork -VMHost abc.com).VirtualSwitch.Name` however could you get multiple switches returned?

Comment: It will always be a single switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is PowerShell does not know how to compare those objects. Even if they had the same data they are technically two different objects ([a blog post touches on this subject](https://www.madwithpowershell.com/2018/01/comparing-powershell-objects-for.html)). At the end of the day if you are just comparing the names then do your comparison on just those.

```
$VMHostVirtualSwitch = (Get-VMHostNetwork -VMHost abc.com).VirtualSwitch.Name
$Cluster = Get-Cluster -VMHost abc.com 
$VMHosts = Get-Cluster $Cluster | Get-VMHost
[int]$Switchcount=0

foreach ($VMHost in $VMHosts){
    $CurrentHostVirtualSwitch = (Get-VMHostNetwork -VMHost $VMHost).VirtualSwitch.Name
    if ($CurrentHostVirtualSwitch -ne $VMHostVirtualSwitch) {
        $Switchcount++
    }
}

if($Switchcount -ge 1) {
    Write-Output "FAIL"
}
```

Now you should just be comparing strings which will get you more predictable results. I have only change the variable expansion in the above example. You might have some error checking to do to account for.

Something like this might be shorter then your loop

```
$badHosts = $VMHosts | Where-Object{(Get-VMHostNetwork -VMHost $_).VirtualSwitch.Name -ne $VMHostVirtualSwitch}
if($badHosts.count -ge 1) {
    Write-Output "FAIL"
}
```

---

`Compare-Object` would also be a way to go for this, especially if there was multiple properties you were comparing: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576496/powershell-how-to-tell-if-two-objects-are-identical). Since we are boiling down to simple strings I think what I propose should suffice.

Comment: I am at a loss to find the "article" that actually explains what is going on here. Basically VMware never gave PowerShell the knowledge on how to compare the objects you have here.